# Why does my code no longer delete the second element after deleting the first one?

Tags: javascript

I have a JS code and I am trying to make a button delete its parent element, it works, I could remove the second element then the first, but when I remove the first one, I can no longer delete the second one, it returns "btn[i] undefined".

```js
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
let div = document.getElementsByClassName('image');

//console.log(btn.length);

for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function() {
    btn[i].parentElement.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img alt="First">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img alt="Second">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Teemu well I could delete them in reverse, second then first, it works, but when I delete the first one, then second that's where the problem occurs, which I don't get. Both buttons have their own parent element.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a live HTMLCollection. If you remove an element from the page then it also gets removed from the collection messing up your indexes.

Comment: Closely related: [Strange behavior when iterating over HTMLCollection from getElementsByClassName](/q/15562484/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection` which *updates dynamically as the DOM changes*. This means, when you remove a button that was matched by your query selector, the collection updates dynamically and the array indices of each element change.

You start with two buttons with indexes `0` and `1`. When you remove the 0th element, all subsequent elements "shift down" and occupy the space you just freed up. This means the button that was at `btn[1]` is now at `btn[0]`, and when you attempt to run `btn[1].parentElement...`, you're access outside the bounds of the collection

In order for your code to work, you need to access the element that was clicked, *not* the original array of `btn` elements:

```js
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
let div = document.getElementsByClassName('image');

//console.log(btn.length);

for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function(event) {
    event.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img alt="First">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img alt="Second">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, that explanation makes a lot of sense, I was thinking about it, that after deleting the first element it would turn the 2nd element's index to [0], and since my loop increases the value of i, my remove function would be pointing at a non existing element, hence it's undefined, but I couldn't think of a way to turn the logic into code. I didn't know that you could write the function that way to point it correctly. I am fairly new to JS, thank you so much for your help and explanation.